# Not able to read the desired excel file as output in Python

Tags: python, excel, powershell, pandas, output

I am trying to read an excel file in Python(2.7.13). For this I created a sample file, Book1, with following entries -

[image]

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 Book1 = pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book1.xlsx")

 print(Book1.head())
```

After writing the above program and executing it in Powershell, I got the following output which I don't understand.

[image]

What are the 0,1,2 in first column and why the value of E cell changed from 7 yo 7.1 ? Can someone explain this to me? Is there something wrong with the program?

I apologize if the uploaded pictures are not appropriate here. I don't know any other way to input such data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0,1,2 are the row indices, since you didn't pass a header, the first row has been automatically converted into a header.

Now, we can't have two columns with the same name, and so the 2nd 7 has been converted to 7.1

To correct this, you can try :

`no_of_columns = 5
Book1 =pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book1.xlsx",header=None,name=range(no_of_columns))`

Note that you need to know the number of columns before hand to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is reading the first row as the header column. Since it wants to avoid conflict in naming columns, the first `7` column gets to keep its original name. The second `7` would create a collision, so pandas changes it to `7.1`.

Set `header=None`. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for a full description of the parameters.

You can specify the `names` of the columns as follows.

```
Book1 = pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book1.xlsx", header=None, 
                      names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
```

The 0, 1, and 2 are the indices of the rows. You can refer to a row using these numbers.

```
>>> Book1[0]
1  3  7  2  7.1   <- column names
2  2  3  2    1   <- values in row 0
```